# Explicit calculation of condition number of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, condition-number, robotics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), the condition number is defined as follows:

Assume the linear system of equation $$Ax = b.$$
Let $e$ be the error in b, then the error of the solution $A^{-1}b$ is $A^{-1}e$. The ration between the relative error of the solution to the relative error of the right hand side is $$\frac{\frac{\left|\left|A^{-1}e\right|\right|}{\left|\left|A^{-1}b\right|\right|}}{\frac{\left|\left|e\right|\right|}{\left|\left|b\right|\right|}} = \frac{\left|\left|A^{-1}e\right|\right|}{\left|\left|e\right|\right|} \frac{\left|\left|b\right|\right|}{\left|\left|A^{-1}b\right|\right|}\text{ , where}$$

$\left|\left|\cdot \right|\right|$ presumably denotes an arbitrary norm.

We know want to know what the maximum value of this error could be, and define this as the condition number $\kappa(A)$

\begin{align}\kappa(A) &= \max_{e,b\ne 0}\left\{\frac{\left|\left|A^{-1}e\right|\right|}{\left|\left|e\right|\right|} \frac{\left|\left|b\right|\right|}{\left|\left|A^{-1}b\right|\right|} \right\} \\ &= \max_{e\ne 0}\left\{\frac{\left|\left|A^{-1}e\right|\right|}{\left|\left|e\right|\right|}\right\}\max_{b\ne 0}\left\{ \frac{\left|\left|b\right|\right|}{\left|\left|A^{-1}b\right|\right|} \right\} \\
&= \max_{e\ne 0}\left\{\frac{\left|\left|A^{-1}e\right|\right|}{\left|\left|e\right|\right|}\right\}\max_{x\ne 0}\left\{ \frac{\left|\left|Ax\right|\right|}{\left|\left|x\right|\right|} \right\}  \\
&= \left|\left| A^{-1}\right|\right|\left|\left|A^{\vphantom{-1}} \right|\right|.\end{align}
This last step follows directly from the definition of an operator norm
$$\left|\left|A^{\vphantom{-1}} \right|\right| = \max_{x\ne 0}\left\{\frac{\left|\left|Ax\right|\right|}{\left|\left|x\right|\right|}\right\}.$$

So far so good, every step for this derivation makes logical sense. However, how does one go about actually calculating the operator norm $\left|\left|A\right|\right|$?

The frobenius norm 
$$\left|\left| A \right|\right|_F =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\left|a_{ij}\right|^2} = \sqrt{\text{tr}\left(A^TA\right)}$$
is not an operator norm, and using it would calculate an upper bound for $\kappa(A)$ instead of the value itself
$$\kappa(A)\le \left|\left| A^{-1}\right|\right|_F\left|\left|A^{\vphantom{-1}} \right|\right|_F.$$
Nonetheless, this definition is often utilized in the field of robotics for the calculation of $\kappa(A)$. See for example this excerpt of [C. Gosselin, J.Angeles](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/mechanicaldesign/article-abstract/113/3/220/429358):

[image]
[image]

It is even mentioned that the (normalized) frobenius norm is equivalent to the operator norm!

What am I missing here? Is this some sort of special case? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? The condition number is really a qualitative indicator, so the norm used is (within reason) irrelevant, and the Frobenius norm is easy to compute (albeit you still need $A^{-1}$).

Comment: I want to calculate $\kappa(A)$. The derivation of this value is given in terms of a general operator norm. The frobenius norm, which is the most straight forward approach towards calculating a matrix norm, can't be utilized here, as it only gives an upper bound for $\kappa(A)$ (due to not being an operator norm). Therefore, given an arbitrary numerical $3\times3$-matrix, what norm can I use to explicitly compute $\kappa(A) = \left|\left|A^{-1}\right|\right|\left|\left|A\right|\right|$? What is even more confusing is that, in the literature excerpt mentioned, this differentiation is not made.

Comment: Use the spectral norm if you need an explicit value, but again, practically it is really more qualitative.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the paper is incorrectly assuming that $\left|\left|J\right|\right| = \sqrt{\text{tr}(JJ^T)}$ (frobenius norm) is an adequate definition of $\left|\left|J\right|\right| $ in the context of the calculation of $\kappa(J)$? This definition is used all throughout robotics, so this strikes me as somewhat weird.

Comment: It is a little difficult to give an adequate response in a comment and indeed on my phone. When they say norms are equivalent it doesn't mean equal it means there are bounce relating them.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could further elaborate on this if you find the time, this unforunately doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: I am saying that you can use **any** norm.

Comment: But how does that comply with the fact that $\left|\left|A^{\vphantom{-1}} \right|\right| = \max_{x\ne 0}\left\{\frac{\left|\left|Ax\right|\right|}{\left|\left|x\right|\right|}\right\}$ only holds true for operator norms? For the frobenius norm, this relationship is $\left|\left|A^{\vphantom{-1}} \right|\right|_F \ge \max_{x\ne 0}\left\{\frac{\left|\left|Ax\right|\right|}{\left|\left|x\right|\right|}\right\}$, which is not equivalent.

Comment: It really depends on what you are using the condition number for. The condition number is a measure of the sensitivity of the solution with respect to $b$ perturbations. The definition uses an operator norm as you have noted, and that will give one sensitivity. However, calculating the spectral norm is expensive and the precise value is typically not hugely important, so one can use a less expensive norm.

Comment: But, when one says two norms are equivalent, it means that there are $a,b>0$ such that $a \|x\|_1 \le \|x \|_2 \le b \|x\|_1$ where the $\|\cdot\|_*$ are two different norms.

Comment: It is a general fact that any two norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.

Comment: @copper.hat But $\kappa(A)$ it is defined using an operator norm, how can I just fall back to using a non-operator norm after the derivation? The lack of mathematical rigorosity is what's bothering me about all of this, the same way that treating differentials as fractions does.

Comment: I added a rambling answer/comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment. Really a collection of comments...

First, there are many ways of defining condition numbers. All boil down to computing
or estimating 
the worst case sensitivity of a solution to a perturbation in data. A good reference is "Matrix Compuations" by Golub & Van Loan, Section 2.5, "The Sensitivity of Square Linear Systems".

As you noted above, if $Ax=b,Ax'=b+h$, then
${\|x'-x\| \over \|x\|} \le \kappa(A) {\| h\| \over \|b\| }$, and this relationship 
holds for a norm and its corresponding operator norm.

The point is to have some estimate of the sensitivity of relative errors.

For a given norm $\|\cdot\|_*$ a standard way of defining the $*$-condition number is $\kappa_*(A) = \|A\|_* \|A^{-1}\|_*$. This definition can be used with **any** norm but
the **direct** relevance to a particular problem (such as above) usually requires that the norms be consistent (that is the matrix norm is the induced norm).

On a finite dimensional space (matrices here) any two norms are equivalent, that is
for two norms $\|\cdot\|_a, \|\cdot \|_b$ there are constants $a,b>0$ such that
$a \|A\|_a \le \|A\|_b \| \le b \|A\|_a$, hence we have
$a^2\kappa_a(A) \le \kappa_b(A) \le b^2 \kappa_a(A)$, so, **the condition numbers are
also equivalent in this sense**.

Just for the record, we have $\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F \le \sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$, where
$\|\cdot\|_2$ is the spectral norm. Note that $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A^TA)}$.

Note that the norms $\|A\|_s = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^TWA)}$ and 
$\|A\|_2 = \max_{\|x\|_2 \le 1} \|Ax\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(A^TA)}$ are equivalent
but they are **not** equal (I'm not sure what frame invariance means, I presume it
means rotation invariant, but that is irrelevant here).

So, presumably you are wondering why not just deal with the spectral norm (norm induced
by the Euclidean distance)?

The issue is that computing the condition number with the spectral norm is relatively expensive (in addition to computing the inverse), so a cheaper alternative is used if
reasonable. Generally it is not required to compute the condition exactly, so a
cheaper approximation suffices. (For example, I have seen code where the condition was estimated
by computing $\max_k(\|Ax_k\|)$ for a small number of vectors.)

If one is performing computations and the luxury of a condition estimate
is available then it gives some 'quantitative' measure of how much relative
errors in the input data are amplified and hence a degree of confidence in the results.

And as a complete aside, this illustrates why operations with orthogonal
matrices are stable numerically, as we have $\kappa(Q) = 1$ in this case. (Again
with the spectral norm.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this clears a lot of things for me! So instead of using the mathematical definition of $\kappa(A)$ and calculating the exact condition, they just evaluate it using the frobenius norm with the relationship $\kappa_F(A)\ge \kappa(A)$. But since this will be used for an optimization algorithm, whose sole objective is the minimization of $\kappa(A)$, this is doesn't matter, and only the relative change of the index is important.

Comment: I don't follow your last sentence. I don't know what they are doing so I can't comment on that. Also, I think the last sentence in the excerpt above is asserting that the Euclidean condition number is equal to the ratio of the largest and smallest singular value, which **is** correct. But not equal to the Frobenius condition number.