# Can the computation of condition numbers be written in functional form？

Tags: optimization, condition-number

Given an $n \times n$ matrix M, I want to optimize the condition number $\text{cond}(AM)$, where $A$ is a $m\times n$ ($m>n$) matrix.

I should write the computation of condition number $\text{cond}(AM)$ in functional form like $f(A)$, so that I can perform operations (such as differentiation) on the matrix $A$. My question is that how should I write this $f(A)$ ?

I'm not sure whether it is a stupid question or not, thank you in advance anyway.

Comment: For a given norm, condition number of a square matrix $A$ is defined by $\kappa(A)=\Vert A \Vert \Vert A^{-1}\Vert$. This is a functional form. But in your case $AM$ is not square...

Comment: Thank you for your time. I know that $\kappa(A)=\left \|A\right \| \left\| A^{-1}\right\|$, but if I use L2-norm (as commonly used), how can I take the derivative of $\left \|A\right \|$ with respect to $A$？

Comment: I suggest you the following paper: https://doi.org/10.1137/100795097

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483087/explicit-calculation-of-condition-number-of-a-square-matrix